# How to Lock Jinternal Frame inside JDesktopPane 

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane, jdesktop

I am using `JDesktopPane` and `Jinternal Frame`.

I want to Lock `Jinternal Frame inside JDesktopPane` .

Suggest which method or property needs to change.

Comment: How do mean "lock", unmovable? Unresuzabe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could

1. Supply your own [`DesktopManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DesktopManager.html) and manage the `setFrameBounds` method
2. Implement your own internal frame & override the `setBounds(x, y, width, height)`, & maintain the position by supplying your own x, y values to the super call.